# how to remove space in TR and TD

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry I am newbie in designing I am trying to design a table that show like this 
[image]

I tried this code

```
.itemdisplay {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;  
display: table-cell;}
```

with html tag

```
            <table style="width: 100%; border-style=; " >
            <tr>
                <td class="itemdisplay">
                   <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample1
                </td>
                <td class="itemdisplay">
                   <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample2
                </td>
                <td class="itemdisplay">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample3
                </td>
                <td class="itemdisplay">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample4
                </td>
            </tr>
```

but the output display was wrong, its display like this
[image]
any idea how to edit CSS? border line is not display too. thanks.

Comment: style the checkbox and the text separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a bit more CSS. Remove the inline style from the table and add the CSS below to your code.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapses the margins between cells */
    width: 100%;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: block; /* Forces a new-line after checkbox */
}
.itemdisplay {
    border: 1px solid #000000; /* Creates border for TDs */
    padding: 10px; /* Adds some padding to TD, adjust if needed */
    text-align: center; /* Centers the text in TDs */
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2LyLxjx/).

If you need to put text beside the checkboxes, wrap the checkboxes within `label` elements, and set `display: block` to `label`s instead of `input`s.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```css
table tr td {
 border-bottom:1px solid blue;    
    border-left:1px solid blue;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
    <table style="width: 100%; "  >
        <tr>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
               <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample1
            </td>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
               <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample2
            </td>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample3
            </td>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample4
            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
               <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample1
            </td>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
               <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample2
            </td>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample3
            </td>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample4
            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
               <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample1
            </td>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
               <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample2
            </td>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample3
            </td>
            <td class="itemdisplay">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" />sample4
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like something like this.
CSS:

```
    table{
    width:100%;
}
table tr td{
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
.itemcheck{
    float:left;
}
.tdText{
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <input class="itemcheck" type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" /><div class="tdText">sample1</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input class="itemcheck" type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" /><div class="tdText">sample2</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="itemcheck" type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" /><div class="tdText">sample3</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="itemcheck" type="checkbox" value="1" name="chck" /><div class="tdText">sample4</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

set a line height of your desire and adjust the position of thetextbox.

bootply here:- http://www.bootply.com/N5EPFSq94P